# Show parts of the result of an SQL statement using PHP

Tags: sql, select, php, mysql

I have an SQL query which returns a set of data (around 40-50 tuples).
I would like to display the results 5 at a time on an HTML page using PHP.

I already managed to have the right SELECT statement, but i am having problems to display the results 5 by 5 using a "more" button.

Can you please help?
Note that every time i call the query, the data is being randomized, so it is not possible to set limits and call the query again. I have to find the method to store the results somewhere, and then show them 5 by 5.

Answer (score 3):

> so it is not possible to set limits and call the query again.

Yes it is if you use the same seed.

For instance

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE condition ORDER BY RANDOM(seed) LIMIT start, num
```

You generate seed once in your PHP and reuse it for the next calls (pass it with `GET` or save it into a session var)

Comment: That's actually a better idea than mine. Very nice!

Answer (score 1):

The probably easiest way to do this is using sessions:

```
session_start()
[..] // Your query stuff..
$ids = array();
while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) !== false)
{
   $ids[] = $row['id'];
   // probably output
}
$SESSION['ids'] = $ids;
```

The idea is to store the IDs of your query in the order they rows were returned. When a user clicks on "more" you just fetch the next 5 IDs from the array in the session and build your SQL-Query to fetch the rows.

Hope that helps.

Cheers,
Fabian

Answer (score 1):

You can actually load all your data in your query and store them somewhere for examples in `DIVs` and for the first div, you show 5 rows and for the rest of the divs that contains 5 rows each you hide them initially on and when more link is clicked you show them again. In fact, you can get an idea from **[this script](http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2009/12/23/javascript-active-content/)** too written for the same purpose.

```
<div id="div_1">
 5 rows here, this is shown by default
</div>

<div id="div_2">
 5 rows here, this is hidden initially
</div>

<div id="div_3">
 5 rows here, this is hidden initially
</div>
and so on.
```